# Is it possible to query multiple realms at once if a user has admin privileges? Or have a shared realm that multiple users can write to at once?

Tags: swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I’m brand new to realm and have been digging around in the docs all day today. I come from a sql background and am struggling finding out if what I want done can be accomplished with realm.

I’m wanting to create an app that allows normal users to fill out a simple form, and allow admins to access (read only) these forms. Ideally the admin would see all forms created by users listed in a tableview.

After completed the swift tutorial online, I get the impression that only the user who created the realm object can access it…

Is it possible to accomplish what I described above with realm?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to query multiple Realm files at once currently. In your use case, I recommend you to share one account (created automatically on your application), write multiple users' data to one file. Or sharing one file for multiple users by using Realm's permission change feature, see also https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#modifying-permissions